# Insert content of a file to another file on Linux

Tags: linux, file, sed, awk, cat

I have two files. I want to insert the content of the first file(`file1`) to the second file (`file2`) between some codes (second file is a script). For example the second file should look like this

```
upcode...
#upcode ends here
file1 content
downcode ...
```

upcode `#upcode ends here` and downcode should never change.

How this can be done?

Comment: what is `upcode` and `downcode`. Depending on what they are, the solution may change.

Comment: BTW, if all you want to insert `file1` at the beginning (because `downcode` really dnt have any significance)...do something like this -- `echo "#!/bin/bash" > file2.tmp; cat file1>> file2.tmp; cat file2 >> file2.tmp; mv file2.tmp file2`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. However, I would like to see a general solution when instead of  #!/bin/bash" there are lines of codes.

Comment: You should delete `#!/bin/sh` from your question, since that is what is `upcode` for you...right?

Comment: I put it to there to point the place where upcode ends. It is better to change it to "upcode ends here"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a script to do that (note that your start tag has to be unique in the file)--

```
#!/bin/bash

start="what you need"

touch file2.tmp

while read line
do
  if [ "$line" = "$start" ]
  then
     echo "$line" >> file2.tmp
     cat file2 >> file2.tmp
  fi
  echo "$line" >> file2.tmp
done < file1
#mv file2.tmp file1 -- moves (i.e. renames) file2.tmp as file1.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try `sed`:

```
sed -e '/file1 content/{r file1' -e 'd}' file2
```

- `/pattern/`: pattern to match line
- `r file1`: read file1
- `d`: delete line

Note: you can add `-i` option to change file2 inplace.

Comment: That seems to be a very good solution but I didn't understand it. We search for a string, like  "#upcode ends here" in file2 and then intert file1 content after it, as I understood from your solution more and less. Why we need to read file1?

Answer (score 1):

```
while IFS= read -r f2line; do
    echo "$f2line"
    [[ "$f2line" = "#upcode ends here" ]] && cat file1
done < file2 > merged_file
```

or to edit file2 in place

```
ed file2 <<END
/#upcode ends here/ r file1
w
q
END
```